# How update list of items on Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How update list of items on Firebase database. I can use setValue for set new list, but I could't find how add one item of list. (I don't want send all items of list for update only one item).

On this example I try to do this, but method ref.updateChildren don't work correctly. It's show me databaseReference, but I don't see any change on Firebase.

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("apps");
        for (final App app : apps) {
            ref.child(app.getFirebaseKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        ref.setValue(app.getFirebaseValue());
                    } else {
                        //check need add my phone or no.
                        FirebaseApp firebaseApp = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseApp.class);
                        String myPhone = app.getFirebaseValue().getPhones().get(0);
                        if (firebaseApp.getPhones().contains(myPhone)) {
                            //do nothing
                        } else {
                            firebaseApp.getPhones().add(myPhone);
                            Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            updates.put("phones", firebaseApp.getPhones());
                            ref.updateChildren(updates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                    if (databaseError == null) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "databaseReference=" + databaseReference);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "databaseError=" + databaseReference);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my mistake. I used ref in inner class intead of ref.child(app.getFirebaseKey());